# Formatting the POST array to an SQL insert\update string in codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to automate form creation and submission in codeigniter.

Basically what I want is to find a way to go over all the data in the POST array and format it correctly to an insert or update sql query.

The problem is I don't know how to access to whole POST array in CI, all I know of is the $this->input->post(field_name) way which only gives you a specific field.

Ideally I would want to send the POST array to the $this->db->insert_string() or $this->db->update_string() to do the job for me.

I know I can still use the php native $_POST array, but this is not recommended and not as secure as CI's input class.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks,
Amos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found out that the input class cleans the $_POST array automatically (not talking about XSS cleaning) and so the only advantage to use `$this->input->post(something)` is that it checks if that key exists.

Since I need the whole array I don't need that check and can safely use `$this->db->insert_string($_POST)`.

If I you do want XSS cleaning you can either turn it on globally in the config or use geocine's answer (I would go for a mix of the 2 examples he gave).

Another way to go if you want the whole array with XSS cleaning and without it turned on globally is to go with WanWizard's Input library extension found here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/172705/#821150

Comment: nice library. I hoped I answered your question in any way by checking my answer anyway. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = $this->input->post($key);
  //do something
}
```

or

```
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
for($i=0,$max=count($keys);$i<=$max;$i++)
{
   $value = $this->input->xss_clean($_POST[$keys[$i]]);
   //do something
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, actually a mix of the two examples you gave is a great way to do it. But eventually I found out that the input class cleans the $_POST array automatically (not talking about XSS cleaning) and the only advantage to use $this->input->post(something) is that it checks if that key exists, and since I need the whole array I can don't really care and can safely use $this->db->insert_string($_POST).